# Deleting values from an element of a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

Column 2 of cell array X provides me with the following codes:

> '00000127'
>
> '00010121'
>
> '00040486'
>
> '00003702'
>
> '00010077'
>
> '00000002'
>
> '00000050'

etc …

And I only want to have the last numbers (the numbers on the right), for instance like this:

> '127'
>
> '10121'
>
> '40486'
>
> '3702'
>
> '10077'
>
> '2'
>
> '50'

I am finding difficulties, because I want to erase the zero values I have on the left side of the element. So, unless they are in between two numbers or on the right of other number, zero values should go out.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sort of messy approach -

```
X(:,2) = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(cellfun(@str2num,X(:,2)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

`str2num` should automatically do that:

```
newcell=cellfun(@(x) str2num(x), cell, 'UniformOutput',false);

newcell=

    [  127]
    [10121]
    [40486]
    [ 3702]
    [10077]
    [    2]
    [   50]
```

And if you need them to be strings:

```
newcell=cellfun(@(x) num2str(str2num(x)), cell, 'UniformOutput',false);

newcell=

   '127'
    '10121'
    '40486'
    '3702'
    '10077'
    '2'
    '50'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
X(:,2) = cellfun(@(s) regexp(s, '(?<=^0*)[^0]\d*', 'match'), X(:,2));
```